# TypeError: Image data cannot be converted to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, opencv, matplotlib

I got a problem with the code:

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img1 = cv2.imread('images\colombia_city.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('images\colombia_city_2.jpg')

#img = img1 + img2
#img = cv2.add(img1,img2)
abc = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.7,img2,0.3,55)

plt.imshow(abc)
plt.show()
plt.title("Weighted"); plt.axes()
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
```

According to ** Visual Studio ** the problem this one in:

> plt.imshow(abc)

When I proved the program in another IDE, the program runs normally.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode shows you an error because of "pylint".

This is just a linter telling you that there is an error.

I have got same problem when using OpenCV. There are some other posts that suggests we need to include it to whitelist.

https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1465